# Getting connection string with DotMemory

Tags: dotmemory

I'm trying to get connection string using DotMemory. I can get the connection string but it seems the password is removed.

What I expect
"Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

What I get
"Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;"

Is DotMemory removing the password or the password simply not exists in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it does not exists in memory or presented there in the encrypted form. dotMemory (if you mean [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)) does nothing special with any memory data, just display it as is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it is JetBranks dotMemory. The thing is its too good to be true because I know the password string is there, I don't encrypt it or do anything fancy, I just use it to connect to database.

Comment: I finally found the password, interestingly its not in connectionString variable. Do you know if its possible to search for object based on variable name?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no possibility to find an object using field name or value for now.
What about encryption, standard types used to pass connection string for database usually take some steps to hide password from memory for security reason.